# Nginx Newbie trying to redirect http to https

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, redirect, lets-encrypt

I got my Nginx test server running on a virtual machine on Microsoft Azure. I was able to view my site when going to `http://www.myTestSite.com` until I decided to try redirecting from http to https. I followed [this tutorial](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/222252847-Setting-up-Let-s-Encrypt-on-DreamCompute-with-Nginx) to get a Let's Encrypt certificate, but now `http://www.myTestSite.com` and `https://www.myTestSite.com` just timeout. Here is my new `default` in `sites-available`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index Main.html;
        server_name www.myTestSite.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myTestSite.com/fullchain.pem; $
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myTestSite.com/privkey.pem$
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: take a look at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to see what the problem is.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: Check your VM firewall and Azure security rules.

Comment: Gerald Schneider and Michael Hampton are right. It messed up when I opened port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies everyone, but it turns out I messed up when I tried to open port 443. For the source port range, I put in 443, but I should have put * for everything.